# Moment generating function applied in $2t$

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I am having some trouble with this problem, adapted from Grimmet&Welsh:

If $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ are independent, show that
\begin{align}
M\left(2t\right) = M\left(t\right)^{3}M\left(-t\right),
\end{align}
where $X,Y$ are independet r.v. with mean $0$, variance $1$ and $M(t)$ finite.

How to prove it? Does $X$ and $Y$ needs to have normal distribution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- $M(2t) = E[e^{2tX}]$
- $M(t) = E[e^{tX}] = E[e^{tY}]$
- $M(-t) = E[e^{-tY}]$
- $2X = (X+Y) + (X-Y)$
- If $U$ and $V$ are independent random variables, then $E[f(U)g(V)] = E[f(U)] E[g(V)]$.

Comment: Is this correct?
\begin{align}
M_{X}(2t) = E(e^{2tx}) = E(e^{t2x}) = M_{2X}(t),
\end{align}
so,
\begin{align}
M_{2X}(t) = M_{X+Y}(t) M_{X-Y}(t) = E(e^{t(X+Y)})E(e^{t(X-Y)}) = E(e^{tX})E(e^{tY})E(e^{tX})E(e^{-ty}) = M(t)^{3}M(-t).
\end{align}

Comment: @GuilhermeNetto The step $M_{2X}(t) = M_{X+Y}(t)M_{X-Y}(t)$ could use some explanation, but yes that is correct.

Comment: Pretty much, @GuilhermeNetto .  You can trim some fat by leaving everything in expectation until the end. $$\begin{align}\mathsf M(2t)&=\mathsf E(e^{2tX})\\&=\mathsf E(e^{t(X+Y)}e^{t(X-Y)})\\&=\mathsf E(e^{t(X+Y)})\mathsf E(e^{t(X-Y)})\\&=\mathsf E(e^{tX})\mathsf E(e^{tY})\mathsf E(e^{tX})\mathsf E(e^{-tY})\\&=\mathsf M(t)^3\mathsf M(-t)\end{align}$$

Comment: One more question: Under those circunstances, how can I prove that $\phi(t) = \frac{M(t)}{M(-t)}$ satisfies $\phi(t)=\phi(2^{-n}t)^{2n}$? I need this to prove that $X$ (and $Y$)  has distribution $N(0,1)$

Comment: @GuilhermeNetto I would suggest asking another question; there isn't enough context in your comment for me to understand your question.

Comment: I've did it! This is the link: <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3921746/deduce-that-x-has-normal-distribution-with-mean-0-and-variance-1>